# Horizontal scrollbar affects layout

Tags: html, css, web

When I have a horizontal scrollbar on divs that contain tables of varying lengths it causes a shift in the layout. I'm aware of gutters but they only seem to work on vertical scrollbars? How would I ensure that my layout remains consistent whether or not the scrollbar is present?

[image: Layout Shift]

Answer (score 0):

You can add `overflow-x: auto;` to the parent container of *table*. I don't know if were are looking for this answer but this is how I address this issue:

```
<div style="overflow-x: auto;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Also you can modify your scrollbar styling accordingly:

```
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: white;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: black; 
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
}
```

Also look for this [scrollbar-gutter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-gutter).